# Access container's wireless network from host

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, routing, lxc

I have linux setup on embedded device with many lxc containers. Container **A** has in its network namespace wlan0 interface

(I moved wlan0 from host to container by writing to A's config:

```
lxc.net.0.type = phys
lxc.net.0.link = wlan0
```

, it is required to have wlan0 in container **A** to fulfill other requirements),

but now I need to give host access to external network connected to device using wlan0.

In A's config I also added simple veth bridge configuration:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr
lxc.net.0.ipv4.address = 192.168.1.2/24
```

So on host side I have interface:

```
lxcbr : 192.168.1.1
```

And on **A** container I have:

```
eth0 : 192.168.1.2
wlan0
```

My problem is:

How can I access external network connected to wlan0 from host (and provide access to host for devices in external network)?